# Case statement don't work correctly

Tags: sql-server-2012, case

SQL SERVER 2012
In my `case` server conflict with '='.
why it is not working?
here is my code:

```
SELECT 
TM.CODE_3 as Account,
TM.NAME_3,
TM.CODE_5,
case  TM.Line
 when TM.CODE_5 = '9491'--and RS.SUB1Sel = ('05.11 Penalties and fines')
  then 'R0820-5'
 else TABLE_MAIN_new.Line
 end 
FROM TABLE_Main_new  as TM
left join Danone_Main as DM
on TM.CODE_3 = DM.CODE_3
left join Rep_Struct_2012_N as RS
on TM.CODE_3 = RS.CODE_3
```

Incorrect syntax near '='.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
case  
  when TM.CODE_5 = '9491'--and RS.SUB1Sel = ('05.11 Penalties and fines')
  then 'R0820-5'
else TABLE_MAIN_new.Line
End
```

Comment: thank you very much!
I didn't get it why it's not work when I write TM.Line after case...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
CASE TM.CODE_5
  WHEN '9491'--and RS.SUB1Sel = ('05.11 Penalties and fines')
  THEN 'R0820-5'
ELSE TABLE_MAIN_new.Line
END
```

When you use CASE expression, the WHEN clause should only be a value (true/false depending on your CASE expression). If no CASE expression is used then the WHEN should be a boolean expression. More info [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Comment: When I uncomment other string then code isn't work.
One more question.
Can i write like this:
`CASE TM.CODE_5
  WHEN '9491', '9492' and RS.SUB1Sel = ('05.11 Penalties and fines')
then 'R0820-5'
ELSE TABLE_MAIN_new.Line
END`